# How to use ' in sentences without having it think its closing?

Tags: python

```
bob = input('How old are you? ')
print('You're', bob)
```

It's giving me syntax error because im using ' for you're. Whats the correct way of handling sentences with ' in them?

Comment: You're looking for [escaping](https://www.google.com/search?q=string+quote+escaping&oq=string+quote+escaping&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3104j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do this:

1. Use `"` for your string: `"You're"`.
2. Escape the single quote: `'You\'re"`.

Comment: More than two. There are also raw strings, triple quotes, string formatting, etc.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for the clarification. I have reworded my answer accordingly.